# Changing value of input text after button click using javascript's addeventlistener

Tags: javascript, html, getelementbyid, addeventlistener

I am trying to have the input text that was entered via a text field form change on button click using JavaScript. I'm having difficulty figuring out why it is not working. Any help would be appreciated.

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title> </title>

    <script type="text/javascript">


    function start(){
        var button = document.getElementById("button");
        button.addEventListener("click", buttonPressed, false);
    }

    function buttonPressed(){
        var text = document.getElementById("textField").value;
        text.value = "GMU";
    }

    window.addEventListener("load", start, false);

    </script>

    </head>

    <body>
        <form>
            <input id="textField" type="text" value="">
            <input id="button" type="button" value="Button">
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: The code works. Some error in console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies here:

```
var text = document.getElementById("textField").value;
text.value = "GMU";
```

Take a look at the lines above. You are getting the value of an element and storing it into `text` but you then try to assign `text.value`? Consider this situation:

Say that the `input` currently has a value of "Apples". Doing:

```
var text = document.getElementById("textField").value;
```

Will store "Apples" in `text`. Now you do:

```
text.value = "GMU";
```

Since `text` is a string, and you try to access property `value` which does not exist for strings, it doesn't work - you've access the `value` property one too many times.

Now - note that the variable stores the *value* not reference to the element's value, meaning that in your code above, `text` only holds the property *value*, it's not pointing to the actual element's value property. Thus you would need to directly modify the value property like so:

```
document.getElementById("textField").value = "GMU";
```

This works because you modify the property of the element itself, you don't copy it into a variable.

---

You can alternatively store the element into a variable, and do `element.value = "val"` because an element is an object, and objects have references that point to memory, so when you assign to an object, reference is assigned and it points to the same place in memory.

Comment: Thank you! Will accept once the minimum time passes.

Comment: @Kevin No problem, glad to help

Answer (score 2):

To change the input text on button click you can use `addEventListener` just on the button. Then you can change the input field after that.

```js
var button = document.getElementById("button");
var text = document.getElementById("textField");

button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  text.value = "GMU";  
});
```

```html
<form>
  <input id="textField" type="text" value="">
  <input id="button" type="button" value="Button">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Definitely efficient!